# Alerts, prompts, and a final alert

Tags: javascript, html, loops, prompt

I can't figure out how to make my code to prompt the user for at least 3 times, click button **only once**, then prompt, if the user does not input something then alert shows up, again prompt, then alert, again prompt then alert… once 3 times the user fails to type something then a final alert shows up like **"No more attempts!"** after the final alert is clicked, the DIV background color turns grey, could some someone help me? I know how to turn the DIV background into grey, my issue is with what I suppose should be a loop(prompt, alert,prompt,alert)

```js
var mObjt = {
  userInput: "",

  setInput: function() {
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = mObjt.userInput;
  },

  conRequest: function() {
    if (mObjt.userInput != "") {
      mObjt.setInput();
    } else {
      alert("There is no input!");
      mObjt.popRequest();
    }
  },

  popRequest: function() {
    mObjt.userInput = prompt("Enter a word:");
    mObjt.conRequest();
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" style="width:200px; height:30px; border:1px solid;"></div>
<button type="button" onClick="mObjt.popRequest()">Add Property</button>
```

Comment: Why do you want to program with those alerts and prompts? for security reasons browsers allow you to block repeated prompts from sites

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a block of script that should do what you're looking to do.

```
var mObjt = {
userInput: "",

setInput: function(){
    document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = mObjt.userInput;},

popRequest: function(){ 
var attempts = 0;

while (attempts < 3 && mObjt.userInput === "") {
    attempts++;
    mObjt.userInput = prompt("Enter a word:");
    if (mObjt.userInput === "")
        alert("You must enter a value");
}
if (mObjt.userInput === ""){
    alert("No more attempts");
    //disable work
} else {
    mObjt.setInput();
}

}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with a simple loop.

```
var prompting = function () {

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        mObjt.userInput = prompt("Enter a word:");

        if (mObjt.userInput == "") {

            if (i != 2) alert("You must enter a value");
            else alert("No more attempts");

        else {

            mObjt.setInput();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```